# Java - Serialize the same class in different ways as a json with Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I want to send a class to a frontend component as JSON with a SpringBoot web endpoint. This isn't a big deal. I can do it (and already did it) in different ways.

Now I want to pass a JPA database object to the frontend. Because of Jackson I don't need any helper classes and I can pass the object directly.

Now I have a problem. I have some database attributes in that class, which aren't interesting for the frontend (with some endpoints). I could mark them with @JsonIgnore. But then they will always ignored. But in some cases I want the field in the resulting JSON.

For example: Class A should be passed throw `GET /api/A/` to the frontend, but the `List<B> multipleInformation` should be ignored there. But there is a second call `GET /api/XYZ` where A should passed to the frontend but the `List<B> multipleInformation` should be included.

```java
public class A {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<B> multipleInformation;

...
}

...
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
  @GetMapping(value ="/A", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<A> getCampaign() {
    return new A(); // silly example, because here is no content...
  }

@GetMapping(value ="/XYZ", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<A> getCampaign() {
    return new A(); // silly example, because here is no content...
  }
```

Are there Jackson annotations which would help me or does I need a second class like:

```java
public class AFrontend {
    private String name;
    private String description;
 
    public AFrontend(A a) {
        this.name = a.getName();
        this.description = a.getDescription();
    }
...
}
```

I'm looking forward to your help. Thank you!

T

Comment: you can extend a class, Jackson supports it, A-->(extends)-->B.

Comment: You could use Jackson's [mixin](https://medium.com/@shankar.ganesh.1234/jackson-mixin-a-simple-guide-to-a-powerful-feature-d984341dc9e2) feature

Comment: Thank you the Mixin feature seems to be perfect. But can I still use the result type `ResponseEntity<A>` or need I to choose `ResponseEntity<String>` and parse the result with an own ObjectMapper, where I registered the Mixin Class?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a layer of separation between the JPA entities and the objects, which are being returned as a response from the API.

So for example you have one database-bound JPA entity, which actually represents the way of how data is being stored in the DB, and a couple of variations of response-bound classes, which will have only the required fields to be exposed from the API.

This will give you a much higher level of flexibility in relation to evolving your API separately from evolving your DB persistency layer.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** easy way to do it.

Only thing come to mind is create custom serializer and control it thru thread local variable, but creating another DTO and convert your entity to it will be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson views in order to achieve what you want. Simply create a `View` class, then annotate the fields you want to be included for each view, along with the controller method that handles each request.

For a simple example check the following:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: Here I have multiple problems. 
I can't change the typ in some views. Maybe my class has an attribute of class C, which has different views too. There I have a problem because I set the view to "public" for the outer class, which contains a C. Then I can't set the view to "internal" at the same time without affecting my outer class...

Further I see no way to change the ObjectMapper of a specific controller method in isolation. So I need to create a objectMapper and parse the Object to a json String. But then my swagger commendation shows the wrong result type (String).